# Search for string in a file from a certain line no

Tags: linux, bash

How to search for a string **from/after** certain line in text file using bash script?

E.g. I want to search for first occurrence of `"version:"` string but not at start of file but at line no. say 35 which contains text `*-disk:0` so that I would get product name of disk-0 only and nothing else.
My current approach is as follows where `line_no` was line no. of the line where `disk:0` is present. But sometimes there is vendor name also present in-between the `disk:0` and `version`. At that time, this logic fails.

```
ver_line_no=$(echo $(( line_no + 6 )))
ver_line_text=`sed -n ${ver_line_no}p $1`
check_if_present=`echo $fver_line_text | grep "version:"`
```

**Background:**
I am trying to parse output of `lshw` commmand.

```
*-disk:0
       description: ATA Disk
       product: SAMSUNG 
       physical id: 0
       bus info: scsi@z:y:z:0
       logical name: /dev/sda 
       version: abc
       serial: pqr
       size: 2048GiB 
       capabilities: axy, pqr
       configuration: pqr, abc, ghj
  *-disk:1
       description: ATA Disk
       product: TOSHIBA
       physical id: 0
       bus info: scsi@p:q:z:0
       logical name: /dev/sdb 
       version: nmh
       serial: pqasd
       size: 2048GiB  
       capabilities: axy, pqr
       configuration: pqr, abc, ghj
```

This is the sample information. 
I want to print information in tabular format using bash script.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to cut out the block you want with `sed`, then use `grep`:

```
sudo lshw | sed -n '/\*-disk:0/,/\s*\*/p' | grep 'version:'
```

The `sed` command does not print any lines (`-n`), then finds the block between `*-disk:0` and the next `*` and prints only that (`p`).

Answer (score 1):

`sed` solution:

If you want to search for first occurrence after given line number (e.g. `10`).

```
l=10
lshw | sed -n "${l},$ {/version/{p;q}}"
```

If you want to search for first occurrence after given line content (e.g. `*-disk:0`)

```
lshw | sed -n '/*-disk:0/,${/version/{p;q}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this `awk` that searches for `*-disk:0` in a file to toggle a flag to true:

```
awk -F: '$1 ~ /\*-disk$/{p = ($2 == 0)} p && /^[[:blank:]]*version:/' file
```

```
   version: abc
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to print all lines up the end. The `$` represents the end in `sed`.

```
sed -p '6,$p'
```

Will print lines from 6th line to the end. Be aware of quoting, so that `$` doesn't get expanded.

You want:

```
ver_line_no=$(( line_no + 6 ))
ver_line_text=$(sed -n "${ver_line_no}"',$p' "$1")
check_if_present=$(echo "$fver_line_text" | grep "version:")
```

Notes:

- Backticks ` are deprecated. Use `$( ...)` command substitution instead.
- Always quote your variables.
- Doing `echo $(( .. ))` is just repeating yourself. Just `$(( ... ))`.
- Sometimes on systems without `sed` you can use `cut -d $'\n' -f6-`.

Answer (score 0):

A general solution using awk (assuming that every disk has a version).

File 'find_disk_version.awk'

```
/disk:/ {
    disk_found="true"
    disk_name=$1
}

/version:/ {
    if (disk_found) {
       print disk_name" "$2
       disk_found=""
   }
}
```

Test file 'test':

```
Something_else
       version: ver_something_else
       serial: blabla
       configuration: foo, bar
*-disk:0
       description: ATA Disk
       version: ver.0
       serial: pqr
*-disk:1
       version: ver1
       serial: pqasd
       configuration: pqr, abc, ghj
Something_else_again
       version: ver_somethingelse_again
       serial: foobar
       configuration: bar, foo
*-disk:2
       version: ver2
       serial: pqasd
       configuration: pqr, abc, ghj
```

Output:

```
$ cat test | awk -f find_disk_version.awk
*-disk:0 ver.0
*-disk:1 ver1
*-disk:2 ver2
```

Instead of 'cat test' can be your command 'lshw'

P.S. the script will not work if there is a disk without version.